# notifyAll() throws IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am designing two threads: one has to get the name of players, and the second thread has to wait for the name being set in order to continue, but notify() all in the first thread is throwing the IllegalMonitorStateException error.

```
private NameFecth nameFetch;
private UseName useName;
private Object nameSetLock; 
public static void method{
   nameSetLock = new Object()
   nameFetch = new NameFetch(nameSetLock);
   useName = new UseName(nameSetLock);
   Thread nameFetchThread = new Thread(nameFetch);
   nameFetchThread.start();
   Thread useNameThread = new Thread(useName);
   useNameThread.start();
}

public class NameFetch implements Runnable{
    /*variables and constructers*/

    public void run(){
       /*get name and set the variable somehow*/
       synchronized(nameSetLock){
         notifyAll();
       }
    }
}

public class UseName implements Runnable{
    /*variables and constructers*/

   public void run(){
     while(!nameBeenSet){
       synchronized(nameSetLock){
         try{
           wait();
         }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
       }
     }

}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: this is the complete code ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're calling `wait` and `notify` without synchronizing on the thing you're waiting on or notifying. As documented in `Object.notifyAll`:

> Throws:
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

So this:

```
synchronized(nameSetLock){
  notifyAll();
}
```

should be:

```
synchronized(nameSetLock){
  nameSetLock.notifyAll();
}
```

... and ditto for `wait`. Note that your current code wouldn't even compile as you're using `syncronized` rather than `synchronized`, which suggests that you didn't post your *actual* code. It's possible that in typing out the code you've actually *changed* the problem - in which case you should edit your question to be more representative.

Comment: edited, thanks. I have read the document, but I have no idea what it means, really new to concurrency. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue that you are using the lock incorectly. You synchronized block is on nameSetLock and you are calling your notifyall on your NameFetch object instance (which is the sayme a synchronized(this).

You should do 
nameSetLock.wait when you want to use the lock and nameSetLock.notifyAll to notify.

Comment: If I call nameSetLock.wait() inside useName, will it cause useName to stop?

Comment: What will happen is that when you hit the synchronized block which has namesetlock as the "lock", the jvm will check if another block is currenly synchronized using the namesetlock. If another thread is using this, it will hold until the other synchronized block releases, either by completing the synchronized block or releasing its control by calling nameSetLock.wait.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc of `IllegalStateException`

```
  Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's 
  monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's  monitor
  without owning the specified monitor.
```

You are trying to invoke the wait() and notifyAll() without having that object lock.

Please try what @Jon has suggested it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I forgot to add the synchronized in the method call.