# illegalStateException on nested lock

Tags: java, multithreading

i' m getting this exception but i don't understand why.

```
public Test() {
        globalLock = new ReentrantLock();
        condition = globalLock.newCondition();
    }

public void increaseRow(Integer row) {
    matrixLock.lock();
    try {
        while (countIncreasingColumn > 0)
            condition.await();
        countIncreasingRow++;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       condition.notifyAll();
        matrixLock.unlock();
        synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                matrix[row][j] += 1;
            countIncreasingRow--;
        }
    }
}
```

thread class:

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            test.function(new Random().nextInt(10));
        }
    }
```

stackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" waiting thread for test 18
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
```

i' m getting thie exception on `notifyAll()`. The thread that execute the `global.lock()` block is the owner,so why i'm getting this?

Comment: And what is this mysterious exception? Do we guess? Provide the full stack trace.

Comment: @BoristheSpider wait a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confused with *Monitor Lock*(`Object#notifyAll` & `synchronized`-statements) and *Condition Variable*(`Condition#signalAll` & `Condition#await`).

If you wait on `Condition#await`, you must use `Condition#signalAll` instead of `Object#notifyAll`.

**UPDATE:**
Please see [notifyAll() throws IllegalMonitorStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209552/notifyall-throws-illegalmonitorstateexception) to solve OP's question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i changed the snippet, can you see updates?

Comment: i' m still getting illegalMonitorExeception on notifyAll(), can you explain me why?